# How to call a function with arguments with an array in Powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell

Consider this script in a file called `arrays.ps1`

```
Function CallMe
{
    param($arg1, $arg2)
    Write-Host "`$arg1 is $arg1"
    Write-Host "`$arg2 is $arg2"    
}

$args = "a","b"
CallMe $args
```

Outputs:

```
PS C:\Users\Moomin\Documents> .\arrays.ps1
$arg1 is a b
$arg2 is
```

If I modify it so the last line is

`CallMe $args.Split(" ")`

I get the same output. How can I pass in an array to a function and split the array elements to arguments?

**UPDATE**

This is closer to what I'm doing:

```
Function CallMe
{
    param($y, $z)
    Write-Host "`$y is $y"
    Write-Host "`$z is $z"

}

Function DoSomething
{
    param($x)
    Write-Host "This function only uses one arg: $x"
}

Function DoSomethingElse
{
    Write-Host "This function does not take any arguments"   
}


$funcCalls = (
    ("DoSomething", "c"),
    ("CallMe", ("a","b")),
    ("DoSomethingElse", '')
    )


foreach ($func in $funcCalls) {
    Write-Host "Executing function $($func[0]) with arguments `"$($func[1])`""
    & $func[0] $func[1]
}
```

If I run it this is the output:

```
PS C:\Users\Moomin\Documents> .\arrays.ps1
Executing function DoSomething with arguments "c"
This function only uses one arg:
Executing function CallMe with arguments "a b"
$y is a b
$z is
Executing function DoSomethingElse with arguments ""
This function does not take any arguments
```

Comment: What are you doing elsewhere in your code that is joining your arguments into an array before you call `CallMe`? IOW, are you intentionally creating an array for your arguments (in which case, you're making it harder on yourself), or is some other process giving you an array that you need to handle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can 'splat' an array with `@` to pass each element as an argument to a function.

```
$array = @('a', 'b')
CallMe @array
```

From your updated example, it would be better to store the functions as ScriptBlocks instead of strings and use `.Invoke()` to execute.

```
$funcCalls = (
    ({DoSomething @args}, "c"),
    ({CallMe @args}, ("a","b")),
    ({DoSomethingElse @args}, '')
    )

foreach ($func in $funcCalls) {
    Write-Host "Executing function {$($func[0])} with arguments `"$($func[1])`""
    $func[0].Invoke($func[1])
}
```

Notice that the array of arguments gets passed in to the automatic variable `$args` which is  splatted as `@args`.

#### Edit:

If you are reading your functions from a source where they cannot be stored as ScriptBlocks, you can convert strings to ScriptBlocks with `[scriptblock]::Create()`.

```
$funcCalls = (
    ('DoSomething @args', "c"),
    ('CallMe @args', ("a","b")),
    ('DoSomethingElse @args', '')
    )

foreach ($func in $funcCalls) {
    Write-Host "Executing function {$($func[0])} with arguments `"$($func[1])`""
    $script = [scriptblock]::Create($func[0])
    $script.Invoke($func[1])
}
```

Comment: Thanks I removed @args from the `$funcCalls` array and replaced the last two lines with this one. `[scriptblock]::Create("$($func[0]) @args").Invoke($func[1])`

Answer (score 2):

You're running into this behavior because the array content `"a",b"` is getting [positionally](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx) defined as the value of `$arg1`, since you don't explicitly assign it to either of your defined parameters.  I would also be wary of using `$Args` unless you absolutely intend to, because it is an [automatic variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) in powershell that contains an array of undeclared parameter values that you pass into the function.  You're not using it in your actual function right now, but the variable names are close enough to warrant pointing that out.

Example:

```
Function CallMe
{
    # Foreach array iterate, write to host on a new line.
    $Args | % { Write-Host "Iterate content: $_" }   
}
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> CallMe "a","b" "a" "b"
Iterate content: a b
Iterate content: a
Iterate content: b
```

The strategy for iterating through `$Args` should work in your case if we apply it to any other collection, so long as your goal for "splitting" the array content is to handle each iterate individually.

Example:

```
Function CallMe
{
param
(
  [string[]]$array = ""
)

# Foreach array iterate, write to host on a new line.
$array | % { Write-Host "Iterate content: $_" }

}
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> CallMe "a","b"
Iterate content: a
Iterate content: b
```

Comment: My code was grossly simplified. I have many many functions that will be called with a variable amount of named parameters. I just simplified it to work around this problem. All my functions have named parameters, but I want to call them positionally. Sorry your answer hasn't really helped my understanding. How can I call `CallMe` with an array of two elements as a parameter?

Comment: I've demonstrated in the second example how to call `CallMe` with an array of n elements as a parameter. Explicitly assigning values `$arr1`, `$arr2` in your function and attempting to handle them is ill-advised... you're assuming that the two elements will _always exist_ and that your function can _always_ handle that content. If you're determined on using an array as your input value, you would be much better off working with a collection instead of trying to shoehorn these values into individual parameters.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I have updated it to be closer to what I'm actually doing. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

For the 'CallMe' function don't use commas between the arguments (use spaces):
$funcCalls = (
    ("DoSomething", "c"),
    ("CallMe", ("a" "b")),
    ("DoSomethingElse", '')
    )