# powershell, function calls fomr an array

Tags: arrays, function, powershell

So I am curious how to call a function from an array?
Function example:

```
function test($a, $b)
{
write-host $a
write-host $b
}
```

An array

```
$testArray = @{"test";"testA";"testB"}
```

And the whole bit I want to work is

```
$testArray[0] $testArray[1] $testArray[2]
```

Essentially mimic this

```
test "testA" "testB"
```

Reason for this is I have a few arrays like this and a loop that would go through each one using the custom function call on the data in each array.
Basically trying a different programing style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it sounds like you have an array of arrays to be honest, so we'll go with that. Then let's reference [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201272/how-to-call-a-function-with-arguments-with-an-array-in-powershell?rq=1) which very closely resembles your question, and from that take away the whole `[scriptblock]::create()` thing, and splatting arrays. From that we can come up with this script:

```
function test($a, $b)
{
Write-Host "Function 'test'"
write-host $a
write-host $b
}
function test2($a, $b)
{
Write-Host "Function 'test2'"
write-host $b
write-host $a
}
$TestArray = @() #the correct way to create an array, instead of a broken HashTable
$testArray = @("test","testA","testB"),@("test2","testC","testD")
ForEach($Test in $TestArray){
    $script = [scriptblock]::Create($test[0]+" @Args")
    $script.Invoke($test[1..$test.count])
}
```

If all you have is one array, and not an array of arrays then I guess this is pretty simple. You could do:

```
$testArray = @("test","testA","testB")
$script = [scriptblock]::Create($testArray[0]+" @Args")
$script.Invoke($testArray[1..$testArray.count])
```

**Edit (Capturing):** Ok, to capture the results of a function you should be able to prefix it with `$Variable =` and be good to go, such as:

```
$MyResults = $script.Invoke($testArray[1..$testArray.count])
```

That will capture any output given by the function. Now, since the functions we have been working with only perform `Write-Host` they don't actually output anything at all, they just print text to the screen. For this I would modify the function a bit to get real output that's usable. In this example the function takes 2 parameters as input, and creates a new object with those 2 parameters assigned to it as properties. That object is the output.

```
function test($a, $b)
{
New-Object PSObject -Property @{Value1=$a;Value2=$b}
}
$testArray = @("test","testA","testB")
$script = [scriptblock]::Create($testArray[0]+" @Args")
$MyResults = $script.Invoke($testArray[1..$testArray.count])
```

Now if you ran that you would end up with the variable `$MyResults` being a PSCustomObject that has 2 properties named `Value1` and `Value2`. Value1 would contain the string "testA" and Value2 would contain the string "testB". Any pair of strings passed to that function would output 1 object with 2 properties, Value1 and Value2. So after that you could call `$MyResults.Value1` and it would return `testA`.

Comment: in my actual code i was using hashtables, so I ended up changing things up a little bit. ultimately your example led me to the right path and i got what i wanted to work. :) i used array in my example to keep it simple knowing the answer would get me the info i needed.

Comment: just curious, i am having troubles assigning the output form the function to a variable. the function is returning properly but i can't seem to catch it and assign it to a variable.

Comment: There is no output in your examples given. Write-Host strictly writes to the host. If you want the function to output things use Write-Output

Comment: In my actual code i was trying to use the return statement as an extension of what i have learned so far.
I'll give that a shot then.

Comment: my solution ended up being $returnedData = ([scriptblock]::Create($testArray[0] + " " $testArray[1] + " " + $testArray[2])).InvokeReturnAsIS(). 
Though for my actual code this is different to reflect the use of a hashtable instead of a array, but same principle. the $returnedData variable catches whatever is being sent back when Return is used in the script block. i can update my example to better reflect my intentioned need and how i got it to work if that helps matters.

Comment: It would be good for future users who find themselves in a similar situation and would like to reference your question and solution. To be honest, it shouldn't have had to be that complicated to get an output from your function.

Comment: in hindsight, your right, now i that i got it figured out i find myself wondering why it was hard to figure out in the first place, well knowing is half the battle. i'll update my question when i got a few minutes later today.